# Oracle SQL Developer function does not work

Tags: sql, oracle

Please I can't understand why some function is not working in my Oracle sql Developer. I am trying to select row num 2, but Oracle returns an empty row just the headers.

But when I use row num 1, Oracle returns the first row, if I specify row num <= 2, Oracle returns rows 1 and 2. The vice versa doesn't work, row num >=2 by the way FETCH and offset return error

```
select * 
from PAS.TRANSACTION 
where msisdn in ('1112684179') 
  and rownum = 2 
order by INSERTION_DATE DESC;
```

Comment: This [article on Ask Tom](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html) explains the issues with rownum quite well i.m.h.o.  You should look into the analytical functions like ROW_NUMBER, DENSE_RANK. For example: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by msisdn order by insertion_date desc)`

Comment: seems a logical contradiction .. if you have one line how can you get the line with rownum = 2?

Comment: no i had many line under each number no have entry with just 1 line and under that number i had about 5 records

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because: for the first row it is tested against a `ROWNUM` of `1` and, in this case, `ROWNUM = 2` is false and the row is discarded. Since that row was discarded it is not assigned the `ROWNUM` and instead the next row is tested against that same `ROWNUM` of `1`; the cycle repeats and `ROWNUM = 2` is false and the row is discarded. Repeat, ad nauseum and all rows fail the `WHERE` test and are discarded.

If you want to get the second row then you need to assign every row a `ROWNUM` within an inline view and then once that has been processed then select the second row.

```
SELECT *                             -- Finally, in the outer select get
                                     -- the 2nd row
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,                        -- Second, having ordered the rows
         ROWNUM AS rn                -- then generate the row numbers
  (
    select *                         -- Fisrt, in the inner-most inline
    from   PAS.TRANSACTION           -- view, select the rows you want
    where  msisdn in ('1112684179')  -- and apply the order.
    order by INSERTION_DATE DESC
  )
)
WHERE  rn = 2;
```

*(Also, note that the `ROWNUM` pseudo-column is generated **before** the query is ordered - so if you want it to order first and then number based on that ordering then you need to order within an inline view and generate the `ROWNUM` at the next step - as is done in the example above.)*